# How to display data from a python script in Django?

Tags: python, django

I've created a program that scrape data and store it in a JSON format.

Usually, when I want to display data in Python I use this code:

```
product_list = daily_deals()

for i in range(len(product_list)):
        print("Name: ", product_list[i]["name"])
        print("Price: ", product_list[i]["price"])
        print("Old Price: ", product_list[i]["old_price"])
        print("Link: ", product_list[i]["link"])
        print("Image: ", product_list[i]["img"])
        print()
```

When I wanted to do the same thing in Django, I added the script to the index view (because data will be displayed in the Home page)

```
views.py

def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template("search/index.html")

    daily_deals_list = daily_deals.deal_scraper
    return HttpResponse(template.render({}, request), daily_deals_list)
```

And then in my index.html:

```
{% for product in daily_deals_list %}
    <div class="deal-item">
       <a class="deal-product-link" href="{{ product.link }}" target="_blank">
       <div class="deal-img-block">
           <img class="deal-img" src="{{ product.img }}">
       </div>
       <p class="deal-product-name text-center">{{ product.name }}</p>
       <p class="deal-product-price text-center" style="color: orange;"> 
       <span class="deal-old-price" style="text-decoration:line-through;">{{ product.old_price }}</span>&emsp; {{ product.price }}</p>
       </a>
       </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Are you not seeing data printed in the web browser?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the way I did it in Django is wrong. I'm not seeing anything in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting an empty context when you render your template, the context is basically a dict with all the content you're sending to your template, so if you want to have a list called `daily_deals_list`, your code can be much simpler:

```
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template("search/index.html")
    return HttpResponse(template.render({
        "daily_deals_list": daily_deals()
    }, request))
```

(per your first example, `daily_deals()` returns a product list)

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. However, instead of "daily_deals_list": daily_deals(), the correct way is "daily_deals_list": daily_deals_list

Answer (score 2):

You probaly need to call deal_scraper, so instead of `daily_deals.deal_scraper` do `daily_deals.deal_scraper()`